# Object Refrence Error in MySQL + Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to learn entity framework with MySql database. 
Trying to save the data with following code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text == string.Empty ||
    txtAge.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Please enter proper details first";
        return;
    }

    employee emp = new employee();
    emp.Name = txtName.Text;
    emp.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

    using (entityframeworkEntities context =
    new entityframeworkEntities())
    {

        context.AddToemployees(emp);
        if (context.SaveChanges() == 1)  // Error Part
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Saved Successfully.";
        }
    }
}
```

The code is getting an `Object Reference` error on `if (context.SaveChanges() == 1)` . Even the `emp` is not added to the `contaxt` object.

When I debug the code, the debugger goes to following part:

```
public entityframeworkEntities() :                               
base("name=entityframeworkEntities", "entityframeworkEntities") 
{
    this.OnContextCreated();   
}
```

Even on this part, the debugger comes to the braces but skip `this.OnContextCreated();` line.

Here is my connection string in Web.Config

```
<add name="entityframeworkEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ApplicationWithMySql.csdl|res://*/ApplicationWithMySql.ssdl|res://*/ApplicationWithMySql.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=root;password=root;database=entityframework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Please help me, where am I going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: can you paste the entityframeworkEntities() definition

Comment: It is a constructor of `.edmx`. It does not have a definition.

Comment: try a different connection string name as it looks confusing to have class name and connection string name same. Should not be an issue though both have different type but reduce such factors to find the issue.

Comment: But the name is not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of things u might have overlooked. not so much an answer. quite long to post as a comment

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

a.build clean.

b.build mysql dll into ur bin directory

c.Install nuget packages for MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entities.((right click on assembly and ensure Copy Local is set to true before building)

d.Remove Version=6.3.5.0 tag entirely and build without any versioning on VS.type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" instead of specifying the full version data.